# How to align table view content

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm wondering how would you call a UITable Cell to align next to each other using swift. Is that even possible? Example ->

### |    Home     |  Community  |    About   |

Comment: I don't see any table cells in that picture. Tables grow _down_, not across. Where's the table?

Comment: The cells of a `UITableView` (iOS) does not have *columns*, only rows. You have to setup the cell layout yourself.

Comment: Okay thats what I thought! How would you do that? Thanks